# Changing css properties for selector at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, gumbo

I have a css that defines de skin-class for a custom component, like this :

```
view|PlaceHolderView {
    skin-class:ClassReference('view.skin.PlaceHolderSkin');
}
```

Is there a way to change that value at runtime, so that all instances of the component switch skin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after a bit more digging around.

```
var dec:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('view.PlaceHolderView')
dec.setStyle('skinClass', MyOtherSkinClass);
styleManager.setStyleDeclaration('view.PlaceHolderView', dec, true);
```